# Choosing JS vs. PHP MVC framework for web applications

Tags: php, javascript, model-view-controller, web-applications

I came across another SO question talking about [choosing a web application framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809539/choosing-a-web-application-framework-using-node-js) which provided some good oversight into the back end.

I am currently at a company looking at appifying their web properties and is closing in on making a decision for the front end. Most front end devs know some level of PHP and are in favor of using a PHP MVC framework like Zend. We are also looking at the either Marionette and Angular.js as well.

My understanding is even if they choose Zend, there will still need to be a lot of Javascript built on top of the PHP component of any web app for real-time interactions.

What are the benefits of choosing a fully-loaded JS MVC framework over the PHP MVC frameworks available? Are there any significant security differences from either type of framework to take into account?

Answer (score 3):

PHP is a server side language, which handles application logic at the server side before a page is rendered. PHP deals with things like interacting with a database or sending emails. JavaScript is a client side script which is run after/during the page render and can be used to improve a user interface, or send AJAX requests back to the server to handle server side logic without having to load another page or post a form.

PHP MVC frameworks are used for rapid development, many include templating engines which allow you to create a single page layout file which will load different content depending on what page you have visited. The HTML page templates, or the content included inside them can contain JavaScript which will run in the browser once the page has loaded.

Many PHP frameworks contain lots of PHP libraries to handle many different things at the server side. If your application doesn't need to do anything at the server side, I wouldn't bother using a PHP MVC framework.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I'm looking for a different answer. Mainly, I see that JS MVCs are all the rage for web applications of all kind. Considering this, why shouldn't we use PHP MVCs instead of JS MVCs?

Comment: I don't know tonnes about JS MVC but if you need the ability to do things such as save information to a database or send an email, I doubt JS MVC could handle that.

Comment: @micah Why not use both? It's all about the separation of concerns, so do this server-side with your PHP, and also use a client-side framework for your client-side code to maintain a modular architecture, both server *and* client-side?